# How should I source custom functions into a RMardown file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I often have custom functions saved in a R script that I load into the environment using `source(functions.R)` at the beginning of an R script.

Let's say I now want to create a RMarkdown doc to summarize some of my analysis results, which rely upon these functions. I don't want to have to copy-paste these functions over to the .Rmd file (there are many functions, and I might modify them over time).

How should I load these functions in the .Rmd file? Right now I'm just using `source(functions.R)` in a code chunk in the .Rmd file, but I'm not sure if this is the best practice.

**Example**:
I have two files: `functions.R` and `report.Rmd`

functions.R:

```
mySum <- function(a, b) {return(a + b)}
```

report.Rmd:

````
---
title: "Report"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
source('functions.R')
```

The sum of 4 and 5 is `r mySum(4, 5)`
````

Comment: You could always make a package that contains your functions and lives on your computer; then it would just be a matter of `library(your_package)`.

Comment: True, but that's not all that different from what I'm doing now with `source(functions.R)`. I should say that I was trying to find a solution with `knitr::read_chunk()`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's true, but I would argue the benefit of the package is you won't have to worry about the path to the file containing your functions across different projects.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that.  Do what @N.Williams suggested:  if you have code that is worth re-using, put it in a package.

A package is **much** more than a script containing its functions.  The documentation says what each of those functions should do.  If, in the future, you decide to make a change to what they do, you'll know whether you are violating the implicit contract contained in the documentation.  If you do that, you'll need to check each use of that function to see if the change matters.

Comment: Sounds like putting the functions in a package is the right next move once the functions are pretty worked out, and especially as soon as those functions become useful in any other project.

Answer (score 1):

While it is often suggested to use a package whenever you have reusable code, this is not always the best solution, particularly if you have project-specific utilities. The [`{box}`](https://github.com/klmr/box) package provides a solution that mirrors the functionality of languages like Python where you can write local modules that do not require installation but can be referenced in separate scripts without sourcing everything into your environment. You use Roxygen tags to document and export what you want from each module you write.

You essentially call modules using `box::use(module)`, for remotely installed packages like `box::use(dplyr)` and local modules like `box::use(path/to/module)`. You then can reference functions and other objects using `module$function()`.

---

#### functions.R

```r
#' @export
mySum <- function(a, b) {return(a + b)}
```

---

#### report.Rmd

````markdown
---
title: "Report"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
box::use(functions)
```

The sum of 4 and 5 is `r functions$mySum(4, 5)`
````

---

There's a lot more functionality to `{box}`, so would recommend checking it out!

Comment: Oh wow that's really cool! Didn't know about {box} before, thanks for sharing this. So could I also use {box} if I wanted to use only a specific version of a package? Like, as an alternative to using packages like {renv}, I could just put the actual package source code for a package like {dplyr} in a folder then `box::use(dplyr)` to load that (local) package?

Comment: Yeah, essentially that would be possible, although hard for me to think through a reason not to just use {renv} in this instance as I'm sure you could run into installation/compiling issues, which are things I'm not very aware of ha.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation on source()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/source), the function reads, parses and evaluates its input. So, I guess that's what you want, and I don't know of a more efficient way to load and parse another script in a .Rmd file.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in the same folder and call it just like in any other R file. There are a few options to combine text and the output of a function. `paste0` is one of them.

````
    ---
    title: "test"
    output:
      html_document: default
      pdf_document: default
    date: "19 Juni 2019"
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```

    ```{r cars}
    library(shiny)
    source('functions.R')
    HTML(paste0("The sum of 4 and 5 is ", mySum(4,5)))
    ```
````